# Express - jade cannot find views

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I am currently learning Express ( + Node.js) and I am stuck with a strange error :

```
Error: Failed to lookup view "index" in views directory "../NODE_tests/Tutorial/app/views"
```

I have an index.jade in ../NODE_tests/Tutorial/app/views

```
doctype 5
html
    body
        h1 Hellow World!
```

and my app.js is ( should be ) correct :

```
// require the stuff we need
var express = require("express");
var logger = require("morgan");
var http = require('http');

// build the app
var app = express();

// Set the view directory to /views
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');

// Let's use the Jade templating language
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// Logging middleware
app.use(logger('combined'));

app.all('*', function (request, response, next) {
  response.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  next();
});

// Express routing system ...
app.get('/', function (request, response) {
  response.render('index');
});

app.get('*', function (request, response) {
  response.end('404 error! Page not found \n'); 
});


// start it up !
http.createServer(app).listen(8080, '127.0.0.1');
```

running  node app.js is raising this error ... where am I wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for uncleared reason  the index.jade file was named  index.jade.log , but .log was invisible... ( copy paste from another file...)
sorry for this unnecessary question...

discover it using OSX info on the file